# Puppeteer vs. Chrome: WebGL alpha issues with `additive` blend mode in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, puppeteer, alphablending

When using `THREE.AdditiveBlending` and `THREE.NoBlending` for the particle sprite in a scene, the resulting render is quite different in puppeteer compared with Chrome.

I am trying to understand if there is a setting in puppeteer that I need to adjust to reach parity between the two environments, or if there is a genuine difference between the two rendering engines when it comes to this WebGL content.

What sort of alpha blending issue might cause the scene to appear as it does in puppeteer?

Here is a minimal reproducible example of the issue: https://github.com/mracette/three-alpha-issue. I've also included screenshots of the renders below.

[`THREE.AdditiveBlending`] WebGL + Chrome:
[image]

[`THREE.AdditiveBlending`] Swiftshader + Puppeteer:
[image]

[`THREE.NoBlending`] WebGL + Chrome:
[image]

[`THREE.NoBlending`] Swiftshader + Puppeteer:
[image]

Comment: What kind of results do you get when using different [blending modes](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=material#api/en/constants/Materials)? Does `Multiply` and `Subtract` also give you odd results?

Comment: @Marquizzo I just updated the post to show a comparison with `NoBlending`, which is significantly different. The others look the same across both platforms.